# API Blueprint - Avoid repeating authorization blocks

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary, mson

In API Blueprint, how do I avoid using the same request Authorization header block over and over for every endpoint?

```
+ Request (application/json)
    + Headers

            Authorization: Bearer jsonWebToken
```

Is there a way to template this in a data structure perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately API Blueprint has not such feature (yet)

On the other hand, I can tell you that authentication\authorisation framework is being [worked](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/wiki/Roadmap#features) - so it's possible that in a not so far future this issue will be solved for you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Vincenzo answer is correct. The issue planned to address this is [Authentication](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/11) and [MSON Parameters and Headers](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/286).

In the mean time. One work-around would be to use [Hercule](https://github.com/jamesramsay/hercule) to split your blueprint into multiple parts and transclude the auth headers.